# What happends when a perform_async is called but sidekiq is not running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I was wondering what happends when a perform_async is called on a worker but sidekiq (`bundle exec sidekiq`) isn't running ?

In my app I have some observers that ask sidekiq to do a job when one of my models is trigger (ie create, update or destroy in some cases).

I also have a rake task that builds me a database from some data I have.. When this task is running, it creates several records that trigger my observers who then push jobs in sidekiq queue.

For testing purpose I ran this task without turning on sidekiq and it's working fine, my data is being pushed in mysql !

I know ask myself what is happening to the job my observer tells my worker to do ? Is it still done ? Is it done but not asynchronously ? Is it *not* done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: it is not done. It will be done later

As the name it self is saying it puts it in a `que`. When you turn on `sidekiq` it will read all data from `que` and execute all tasks.

But for this to work you need to have `Redis` working. `Redis` is responsible for saving data in a que, it is a kind of memory. Without `Redis` you would get an error.

Comment: So this means that until I turn on sidekiq, all of it is stored in redis server and it will push them to sidekiq when it does turn on ?

Comment: Yes exactly, this is why it is good, and why it is called async